# Android: EditText inside ArrayAdapter inside Fragment

Tags: listview, arraylist, android-edittext, fragment, android-arrayadapter

situation as described in the title.

Minimal example code here:

```
public class FrgData extends Fragment {
    private View rootView;
    private DataAdapter dataAdapter;

    public FrgData() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.data, container, false);

        ListView dataListView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.Data);
        dataAdapter = new DataAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.layout.data_item);
        dataListView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
            dataAdapter.add(new tData());
        }

        return rootView;
    }

    private class DataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<tData> {
        public DataAdapter(Context context, int id) {
            super(context, id);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;

            if (v == null) {
                v = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.data_item, null);
            }

            return v;
        }
    }
}
```

"tData" is an ArrayList.

"data_item" is a simple number EditText inside a horizontal LinearLayout.

The behavior is totally erratic.
The EditTexts are created perfectly. The problem is that if I select one, the keyboard first is not "number", but alphanumeric. If I select another one, the keyboard changes magically to "number", but the cursor is invisible. I can type, though. When exiting the keyboard, the number either vanishes or gets duplicated in other EditTexts below! These copies seem to appear in equal intervals (of 8 or 12), so I suspect this has something to do with (or the lack of) proper initialization.
I cannot figure out my mistake.

Comment: It works when I reduce the count from 40 to 4. With 5 it does not. This is when I noticed that with 4 lines the keyboard does not overlap the list. With 5 it does. Then I removed some description text I had above the list. Now that there is some more space, it works even with 5 lines... what the hell? Is this a bug in Android???

Comment: Short after the keyboard overlaps the list, the EditText which was clicked on loses focus and the keyboard changes to alphanumeric...

Comment: Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

My current "solution" is to manually(!) add the 40 lines. I works for now, although this is a very ugly situation. Each line requires 3 EditTexts and a SeekBar. The whole Fragment has 160 controls now...
I wonder if there is a better way? The user needs to have an overview of all the other settings when editing one.